# Как использовать несколько цветов в одной строке DrawString C#?

Tags: c#, строки, gdi, рисование

Я использую `DrawString()` и мне нужно что бы одна часть текста была красного, а вторая - желтого. Как такое сделать? Я находил советы как сделать разный цвет для разных строк, но не нашел для ничего для одной

Comment: Покажите код метода отрисовки, отредактируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    string text = "Разноцветный текст";
    int length = 12;
    string firstPart = text.Substring(0, length);
    string lastPart = text.Substring(length);

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    e.Graphics.DrawString(firstPart, Font, Brushes.Red, x, y);

    var size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(
        firstPart, Font, new PointF(x, y), StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

    e.Graphics.DrawString(lastPart, Font, Brushes.Yellow, x + size.Width, y);
}
```

Выводим первую часть текста одним цветом.
С помощью `MeasureString` находим размер первой части текста.
Выводим вторую часть текста вторым цветом, отступив найденный размер.